# Counting four-digit numbers that start with an even (possibly zero), end with an odd, and have no repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Question: In a certain company, employee IDs are strings of 4 digits (that may begin with a $0$).
>
> How many IDs begin with an even digit, end with an odd digit, and have no repeated digit?

Answer:

- First digit: $5$ choices (either $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, or $8$)
- Last digit: $5$ choices (either $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, or $9$)
- Second digit: $8$ choices ($5+5 - 2$)
- Third digit: $7$ choices ($5+5 - 3$)

> Total number of IDs = $5 \times 5 \times 8 \times 7$
>
> Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Aren't there $9$ choices for the second digit? You can have any of the odds or any of the evens not equal to the first digit.

Comment: I think we should start with he restrictions first (first and last caraters in that example) so that's why it should be 8 instead of 9.

Comment: @FreshmanUCSD That makes sense. Your answer looks correct to me as well.